# Поиск обьекта на нескольких Activity

Tags: android-studio

В проекте Android studio есть несколько Activity, на которых расположены обьекты(button) с именами 1-10, 11-20.. и т.д. Как реализовать поиск на главном Activity, что-бы отображать Activity, на котором находится обьект поиска?

Comment: Это никак не сделать. Одновременно активна может быть лишь одна активити, а все остальные следует считать мёртвыми. Т.е. при попытке что-то там искать вы получите NPE. Да, можно извратиться несколькими способами, но это будут жуткие костыли и они будут работать нестабильно. Лучше расскажите какую задачу вы хотите решить - наверняка она может быть решена красиво и изящно, без костылей и хаков.

Comment: Есть несколько планов этажей с расположеными на них аудиториях. Аудитории на форме я представил в виде кнопок. Нужно в поиске найти  план этажа , на котором находится искаемая аудитория

Comment: Вам надо всю информацию об этажах и аудиториях сложить в БД, отображать на экранах их из БД и искать также в БД. Так у вас никаких проблем не будет.

Comment: Благодарен. Буду пробывать